# Is it possible to use custom iOS UI elements like UILabel in augmented reality app

Tags: ios, arkit

I am wondering if I can use UI elements like `UIButton`, `UILabel` in an augmented reality app with ARKit.

Answer (score 2):

If you are also interested in transparency modes for that UIView subclasses try my sample https://github.com/erikhric/ar-menu

You can use different blending modes. I guess .alpha will work for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can use `UIKit` elements by adding them to a `UIView` that's positioned above the view displaying the AR scene (`ARSKView` or `ARSCNView`).

If you create a new project in Xcode and select the "Augmented Reality App" template, you can see that the AR content is just a view like any other `UIKit` view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can place UI elements on top of the `ARSKView` or `ARSCNView` displaying the AR scene:

```
let scanningPanel = UIImageView()
scanningPanel.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.33, alpha: 0.6)
scanningPanel.layer.masksToBounds = true
scanningPanel.frame = CGRect(x: -2, 
                             y: self.sceneView.frame.height-270, 
                         width: 178, 
                        height: 50)

scanningPanel.layer.cornerRadius = 10

let scanInfo = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8, 
                                     y: self.sceneView.frame.height-268, 
                                 width: 160, 
                                height: 45))

scanInfo.textAlignment = .left
scanInfo.font = scanInfo.font.withSize(15)
scanInfo.textColor = UIColor.white
scanInfo.text = "SCAN A SURFACE"
```

**Adding:**

```
self.sceneView.addSubview(scanningPanel)
self.sceneView.addSubview(scanInfo)
```

**Removing:**

```
if(scanInfo.isDescendant(of: self.sceneView)) {
    scanInfo.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: This method worked for me. What didn't work for me is adding a UIView on top of the Scenekit view. The Scenekit view always appeared on top of the UIView.

Answer (score 1):

What worked best for me
in main.storyboard:
- delete SceneView
- add regular UIView
- add ARKit SceneKit View on top of that
- then you can add buttons, etc.

Comment: this did not work for me, the UIView always shows up *underneath* the scenekit view. however, adding the UI elements programmatically, while ugly, does show the elements on top of the scene kit view.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert content of any view on a plane in ARKit like this:

```
let plane = SCNPlane(width: sceneView.bounds.width/3000, 
                    height: sceneView.bounds.height/3000)

plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.anyView`
```

Gestures and taps are automatically sent to that view.
[Try my example](https://github.com/erikhric/ar-menu).

Comment: This works with other views. But if I try this with web kit view them it fails to render content (html ). ( Not working when I try Diffusing web kit content  in arplane)